# How to combine require.js and jquery CDN together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, require

Please, help to combine require.js and jquery CDN together. I have seen a lot of options to do that, but still have a problem with it. After my code below, I have two errors:

1. JQuery is not found
2. problem with a script (where define function placed).

I did everything on prescription from http://requirejs.org/ , but still have those problems.

my code:

```
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"</script>
```

app.js

```
requirejs.config({
'baseUrl': 'js/',
'path': {
    'app': 'app',
    'jquery': '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js',
}
});

requirejs(['app/main']);
```

main.js

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
  $(function() {
    $('body').text('hi!');
  });
});
```

Help me to remove these errors

Comment: can you share the html file

Comment: Do you mean my html page? So it's just little page with some html elements wich work with jQ. Really nothing special.